Fan coil filter access blocked by door frame
I have an indoor hvac that is improperly aligned with the access doorway by 2 inches; as a result I can't install an air filter the intended way. Can I have someone cut a 2 inch wide channel with a router in the left door frame so I can correctly situate my desired inflexible 16x20x1 air-filter into the hvac unit beyond the doorway without compromising the home's structural stability?



Door frames are not structural.  The rough opening framing might be, but that is hidden behind the door frame.  For the size, a hand saw would work also.

It would help if you'd show us the doorway you're actually asking about. It's probably not structurally critical, but it's necessary for good answers.

Added another photo; hard to really illustrate in the pictures though

It isn't hard. Show us the whole door instead of little edges of it. We can answer your actual question with a simple "Sure!", but I prefer to explore less hacky solutions. If I could see the full nature of the door jamb and trim I might have something for you. Back up! Show the door closed, too.

Could you not simply use two 16x10 filters?  If you're worried about gapping at the joint, you can tape that up after installation.  Also, you're gonna be in big trouble when it comes time to replace that unit! :)

I (like @Huesmann) think it's a retrofit installation on that wall, since there's no way the furnace would have fit through that door for install.  I would guess that it also violates minimum manufacturer's clearance requirements around the furnace.  Also, since it looks like the return air is pulled directly through the visible opening in the furnace without any other return ductwork that closing the sliding door will block off being able to pull air through the coils properly.

Frame challenge: there isn't anything sacred about that particular size of filter for your air handler. Choose a different size filter.
It looks like an 18 inch wide filter might be a good compromise if you can find it with suitable length. Even a 16x16 might work out.
Do you see the wide strip of sheet metal along the right edge of the heat exchanger? No air passes through there; filter media pressed against that doesn't serve any purpose anyway. To use a narrower filter you may have to modify the filter-holder brackets, especially the one on the right. A strip of sheet metal, wood, etc could be attached to make the leg of the bracket wider so that it supports a narrow filter.

This helped me rethink the solution; thanks!
